# How do you remotely check if HTTP directory listing is enabled on Linux?

Tags: security, shell-script

I want to be able to automatically test all of my servers to make sure that directory browsing is enabled. How do I do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Create a directory, fetch its contents over HTTP from *localhost* (using `curl`, `wget -O /dev/stdout`, `lynx -dump`, `w3m -dump`, `elinks -dump`) and look for the file list. Example for Apache2, which normally shows *`Index of /directory`*:

  ```
  cd /srv/http
  name="test-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"
  mkdir "$name"
  if curl "http://localhost/$name/" | fgrep -qs "Index of /$name"; then
      echo "enabled"
      rmdir "$name"
  else
      echo "disabled"
      rmdir "$name"
      exit 1
  fi
  ```

  If you are using Lighttpd, nginx or something else, adjust the *grep* pattern.
- Alternative: Learn some `grep` or `perl` and parse the hell out of your configuration files. The exact process depends on the HTTP daemon you are using – their configuration formats are *very* different.

Comment: Nice thanks! Also using curl to get the http response code works for me. 403 means directory listing is disabled, and 200 means it's enabled